# How do I insert text using a context menu for a browser extension?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to create an extension that inserts a date and time by right clicking a context menu icon as a way to start learning javascript and web based development (my experience is exclusively java and python). I thought my idea was simple enough, and I was able to set up the bones of the extension by finding info about it online. I am just stuck on actually inserting text, the only actual purpose of the extension. I'm sure I am just asking the wrong questions when I look things up, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to accomplish what I want to.

This is what I have so far (did not include the popup.html):

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Date Stamp",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Inserts the current date and time at the cursor.",
    "permissions": ["contextMenus", "activeTab"],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    }
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        title: 'Insert Date Stamp',  //this will show up in the context menu
        contexts: ['all'],      //this is used to tell when our context menu item should be displayed, I believe editable will restrict it to text boxes and the like
        id: 'dateStamp'
    });
})
```

content.js:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId === "insertText") {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        function: insertTextFunction
        });
    }
});

function insertTextFunction() {
    var activeElement = document.activeElement;
    if (activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input" || activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === "textarea") {
        activeElement.value += "Test text";
    }
}
```

The context menu item shows up, and I can click on it, but then nothing happens. I have tried putting console.log messages in various places to see if I can figure out where the code is not executing, but nothing ever shows up in the console.

I am also open to the possibility that this is not a beginner level project and I should maybe come back to it once I have some more experience in this area.

Comment: Remove content_scripts and content.js, move the contents of the file into background.js.

Comment: I did try that, still nothing happens. Is there a way to test what is going wrong? I thought putting console messages would help me narrow things down but just none of them execute it seems. I'm not getting any error messages on the extensions page either.

Comment: You need to reload the extension in chrome://extensions page after editing it. See also the [background console](/a/10258029).

Comment: Alright I am getting a console message to run inside the:

| 1. onInstalled.addListener function
| 2. onClicked.addlistener function |

but not in the: 
| 3. if statement inside the onClicked.addlistener function
| 4. insertText function |

Comment: Update: I fixed the if statement in the onClicked function and now I am getting this error: | 

Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'executeScript')

Comment: Add "scripting" to "permissions" in manifest.json.

Comment: That did it!! Thank you so much, what I already had took hours for me to figure out so I'm really glad I didn't have to abandon it. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) for the answer!

1. Move the contents of content.js to the bottom of background.js
2. Delete content.js and the section in the manifest for "content_scripts"
3. add "scripting" to "permissions" in manifest

Here is the updated code:

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Date Stamp",
    "version": "0.6",
    "description": "Inserts the current date and time at the cursor.",
    "permissions": ["contextMenus", "activeTab", "scripting"],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    }
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: 'Insert Date Stamp',
    contexts: ['editable'],
    id: 'dateStamp'
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId === "dateStamp") {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tab.id },
            function: insertTimeStamp
        });
    }
});

function insertTimeStamp() {
    var activeElement = document.activeElement;
    if (activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input" || activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() === "textarea") {
        let now = new Date()
        activeElement.value += now.toLocaleString();
    }
}
```